# What is the point of include.lowest argument in hist?

Tags: r, histogram

In the `hist` function for plotting histograms, there is an argument `include.lowest` with default value TRUE.

From what I understand, this argument is supposed to allow to keep or not keep the lowest bound of the lowest breaks, when the breaks are set as a vector.

But if I try, as a purely artificial example, a command like:

```
 hist(c(1:100), breaks=c(1,2,10,50,100), include.lowest=FALSE)
```

I just get an error:

```
Error in hist.default(c(1:100), breaks = c(1, 2, 10, 50, 100), include.lowest = FALSE) : 
  some 'x' not counted; maybe 'breaks' do not span range of 'x'
```

What happens here is that hist doesn't allow a plot that doesn't take the full data (x) into account. With include.lowest at false, the value "1" from my data wouldn't appear anywhere in the histogram. But since that's the case, what is include.lowest used for? I can't see any situation where setting it to false would make any difference without triggering an error.

Note: In my explanations, I assume I keep the default `right=TRUE`, but if `right=FALSE`, I should just be the same behavior for highest break rather than lowest, right? So I don't think it changes anything.

Some more context: We are working on a graphical interface for plotting graphs using R (It's going to be part of R++ and it's going to be awesome, of course). And as we provide tools for all histograms parameters, we got stuck on that one. If it's not useful for anything and is just a legacy of some old hist version, we might as well not include it, but we wouldn't want to forget it if it can actually be useful.

Thanks for your attention, everyone.

Comment: Seems to me it's just been left in because the C function that does the binning for the histogram expects that argument. There is a check after the binning in `hist.default` to see that the counts sum up to the number of observations, meaning you can't _not_ count something without throwing an error; so I can't think of a scenario where setting `include.lowest = FALSE` would change anything in the histogram and not throw an error, as you said.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. I assume you're asking about the behaviour of `include.lowest = FALSE` in `hist`, and why it produces an error in your example.

This has to do with the way data is binned. Let's take a look at `cut` because this function is closely related to what `hist` does.

```
cut(1:100, breaks = c(1, 2, 10, 50, 100))
#  [1] <NA>     (1,2]    (2,10]   (2,10]   (2,10]   (2,10]   (2,10]   (2,10]
#  [9] (2,10]   (2,10]   (10,50]  (10,50]  (10,50]  (10,50]  (10,50]  (10,50]
# [17] (10,50]  (10,50]  (10,50]  (10,50]  (10,50]  (10,50]  (10,50]  (10,50]
# [25] (10,50]  (10,50]  (10,50]  (10,50]  (10,50]  (10,50]  (10,50]  (10,50]
# [33] (10,50]  (10,50]  (10,50]  (10,50]  (10,50]  (10,50]  (10,50]  (10,50]
# [41] (10,50]  (10,50]  (10,50]  (10,50]  (10,50]  (10,50]  (10,50]  (10,50]
# [49] (10,50]  (10,50]  (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100]
# [57] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100]
# [65] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100]
# [73] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100]
# [81] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100]
# [89] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100]
# [97] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100] (50,100]
#Levels: (1,2] (2,10] (10,50] (50,100]
```

Notice how 1 gets "placed" in bin `NA`. That's because bins are open-closed intervals, e.g. `(1, 2]` means `1` is *excluded* while `2` is *included*.

So coming back to `hist`, the following won't throw an error when using `include.lowest = FALSE`

```
hist(1:100, breaks = c(0, 2, 10, 50, 100), include.lowest = FALSE)
```

[image]

To clarify (based on @MikkoMarttila's comment): Binning in `hist` with `include.lowest = FALSE` is the default behaviour you would expect from standard binning in R using e.g. `cut`. So the option to set `include.lowest = FALSE` is included to be consistent with `cut` and its default open-closed intervals. Most of the times when plotting a histogram you want an interval where the minimum value is part of the interval (which wouldn't be the case when using open-closed intervals), hence `include.lowest = TRUE` by default.

Comment: I assume the OP is asking if there is any reason why one would ever want to use `include.lowest = FALSE`.

Comment: @MikkoMarttila The answer to your question is in my answer: `include.lowest = FALSE` is the default behaviour you would expect from standard binning in R using e.g. `cut`. So I guess it is included for consistency with `cut`. Most of the times you want an interval where the minimum value is part of the interval (which wouldn't be the case for typical open-closed intervals), hence `include.lowest = TRUE` by default. Makes sense?

Comment: Indeed: and the argument has valid uses (that don't throw an error) in `cut`. But the only effect that setting it to `FALSE` in `hist` can have is to cause an error message, right? I suppose it could be useful to assert an assumption that the data you are plotting are strictly positive?

Comment: @MikkoMarttila As I said, I think `include.lowest = FALSE` is critical to ensure consistency with results from `cut`. For example, if you want to extract details from the `hist` return object, and map them to intervals calculated with `cut`; or when comparing results from `hist` with `table(cut(...))`.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. It confirms part of what I was thinking, and helps me better understand the link with `cut`.

If you're curious, and as a result of this discussion, I don't think we are going to provide access to the include.lowest parameter in our graphical interface, although the user will always have the possibility to manually edit the the generated raw code is he/she so wishes (for example to compare results to `table(cut(...))`).

Comment: @MauritsEvers I would agree, if the use of the argument and the subsequent results were _actually_ consistent. But as it is, with `include.lowest = FALSE` and data that match the lower bound, `hist` will not return anything: it will just throw an error; while `cut` will still return a result, just with `NA` values in it.

Comment: @MikkoMarttila But `hist` *will* return a plot, if you change the `breaks` argument as I demonstrate (I even include the corresponding figure for OPs example)! That's exactly the point. Please read my post and comments again carefully.

Comment: Sorry to keep flogging a dead horse; but if you change the `breaks` argument as you demonstrate, it won't matter whether you use `TRUE` or `FALSE` as the `include.lowest` argument: the output is identical. The only time the value of `include.lowest` makes any difference is when you have values in your data matching the lowest value in `breaks`: and the only effect that changing the argument to `FALSE` can have is to throw an error, which is inconsistent with `cut`, and doesn't really have any use other than asserting that there are no values in your data that match the low bound.